How can I take a tag version from my GitHub repo and have it embedded in the DLL my Jenkins pipeline builds?
I have a project stored in GitHub and building a C++ DLL through a Jenkins pipeline. I’m hoping there’s a way that I can have the pipeline build the DLL and embed in the code the branch/tag name it’s building, for access by the calling application. Any ideas?
I was thinking to try using environment variables but that would stop people manually building the DLL on their development machine without configuring the environment variable. Not the best solution…
